# Any way to install a bookmarlet in Mobile Safari from a native app?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch, safari

Any way to install a bookmarlet in Mobile Safari from a native app? Has anyone been able to successfully do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there is no support for this in the API.
The workaround would be to launch Safari from within your app and take the user to a page where you tell them what to do (arrow pointing down to the + sign) with instructions on what they should do next.

Comment: Not true. Twitteriffic for iPhone has an option to install a bookmarklet to Safari from within the App.
I will have a look at how its done and get back with an answer, hopefully.

Comment: It might be that it launches safari to a URL like one of these:
http://www.ipuhelin.com/en/safariplus/

I doubt that you can do this on the fly without killing your own app.